# Test if a method takes a block

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can I verify if `Foobar#some_method` takes a block. Something simliar to `Foobar.new.respond_to?(:some_method)`

```
class Foobar
  def some_method
    yield
  end
end
```

**Why?**

This is useful for testing contract interface. Ensuring the method I stub has an unchanged API.

**Ways I've tried**

```
mth = Foobar.new.method(:some_method)
mth.parameters
```

this returns a list of parameters (what Rspec uses essentially). It works if I have an argument as block like this:

```
def some_method(&blk)
end
```

But if a method uses `yield` instead, I got nothing from `#parameters`.

This is for adding specs for ensuring the interface with the ugly outside world. So I know how a method is used. But if there is an API change, I'd like specs to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I verify if `Foobar#some_method` takes a block.

*Every* method in ruby takes (can take) a block. It may simply choose not to yield. So that's what you need to check, I think: if the method yielded or not.

RSpec has a number of yield expectations: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/yield-matchers

```
RSpec.describe "yield_control matcher" do
  specify { expect { |b| MyClass.yield_once_with(1, &b) }.to yield_control }
  specify { expect { |b| MyClass.dont_yield(&b) }.not_to yield_control }
  specify { expect { |b| MyClass.yield_twice_with(1, &b) }.to yield_control.twice }
  specify { expect { |b| MyClass.yield_twice_with(1, &b) }.to yield_control.exactly(2).times }
  specify { expect { |b| MyClass.yield_twice_with(1, &b) }.to yield_control.at_least(1) }
  specify { expect { |b| MyClass.yield_twice_with(1, &b) }.to yield_control.at_most(3).times }

end
```

So for your case it should be something like this:

```
expect{ foobar.some_method }.to yield_control
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention this works, but I need to stub some methods in the libraries I am using. It'd be nice if I don't do any stubbing, especially considering those are implementation details in the library. Any other alternative?